# How can I handle POST requests in a Lambda function using Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to change a bit of Python code at the moment that is being used as a Lambda function. Currently, the code in question takes a number of parameters that are URLs, and uses the urllib2 library to get the images at those URLs (for example, a URL could be: https://www.sundanceresort.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/nature-walk-1600x1400-c-center.jpg).

I'd like to change this so that the code will handle a POST request that has the image in its body. Looking at some tutorials I thought Flask request might do the trick but I’m confused as to how it would work in this particular case.

At the moment, the relevant code that would be replaced is in three sections:

```
urls = urls_str.split(",")
results = []

    for url in urls:
        headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
        try:
            req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
            image = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

...

def get_param_from_url(event, param_name):
    params = event['queryStringParameters']
    return params[param_name]

...

def predict(event, context):
    try:
        param = get_param_from_url(event, 'url')
        result = model.predict(param)
```

The overall code is [here](https://github.com/abhisuri97/auto-alt-text-lambda-api/blob/master/application.py).

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you dont need flask-request, the lambda infrasture already deserializes everything for you. It doesn't make sense to use  flask because that just replicates what lambda already provides

Comment: check out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html

Comment: @avigil Sweet, so I'm guessing that means I could create a POST method, change `params = event['queryStringParameters']` to `params = event['requestBody']` (or whatever would get the data from the POST body, and then pass it to the other functions in the Python code?

Comment: yes! or you could use a framework like [serverless](https://serverless.com), which manages the api stuff for you

Comment: @avigil So I've changed the Binary Media Types to accept image/jpeg and I've also been able to find this [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-content-encodings-examples-image-lambda.html) but there's nothing about what to do with the function in Python.